# Is there a trial version of Microsoft Sharepoint for website development?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I am asp.net developer and want to learn microsoft sharepoint for website development.

Is there a trial version of MOSS 2007 available that I can install? And what should be the best approach for installing and learning.

Comment: tagged `google-this` because you can get this answer straight from a Google search

Comment: by 'straight from Google search' I mean, copy-and-paste the question for a Google search

Comment: @silky, please note, my comments are not meant to be derogatory. Take them as part of the answer.

Comment: Removed nik's abusive tag. A comment is sufficient, nik. You don't need to abuse tags to get your point across. Flagging it as spam or voting to close it should be good enough.

Comment: @Weblog, If a tag can be used for stating a question should be moved to SU/SF/SO etc, why not a tag to say this could be Googled?

Comment: @Weblog, I tried to explain that the tag was not meant to be abusive in any way. Infact, rather than have various people comment about such things, a tag like this along with simple answers like the ones on this question would be a more graceful method. I do not understand why this would be an abuse of tags.

Comment: I do not think this is as a spam question. Removing such questions would only get more of them here. If they are asked any way, it would be better to let them be answered (like it is done here).

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

[Microsoft Office SharePoint Server 2007 Trial Version](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=2E6E5A9C-EBF6-4F7F-8467-F4DE6BD6B831&displaylang=en)

> This is the x86 version of Microsoft
>   Office SharePoint Server 2007 Trial
>   for Standard and Enterprise editions.

Answer (score 3):

You can download the trial Sharepoint VHD

[Sharepoint 2007 VHD](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=67f93dcb-ada8-4db5-a47b-df17e14b2c74&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you definitely had a look at two resources:

http://myrampup.com

and

http://mssharepointdeveloper.com

Both sites contain a lot of great resources which can help you understand what SharePoint is about from the developer point of view.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Link for 180 day evaluation Sharepoint 2010 VHD

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=751fa0d1-356c-4002-9c60-d539896c66ce